# Curiosity question - Why does "Hi!" get removed at the beginning of posts?

Tags: discussion, editing

Out of habit I write "Hi!" at the beginning of my questions and I noticed it got automatically removed, and then when I edited to add it back in, it got automatically removed again.

I'm just wondering what the reason for this is? It's not that big of an issue; I'm just genuinely curious.

Comment: Try not to think of posting a serious math question on a Q&A site as you would typically write a text, or email to a friend.  Emoji, Hi!, Thanks! don't really contribute any information in the question.

Comment: I think that it was right write "Hi", "Hello" "Thanks" or other concise human communications at begining or for the end of a post but if I understand well from the answer below was considered remove the words "Hi". I think that there are more important concerns than avoid the word "Thanks" in a post, for example a Q&A site  should take care, in my opinion, about that all users treat with respect the moderators (that are persons), or for example take attention about the equity concerning that can be answers with a score that is very large in comparison with other answers showing great maths.

Comment: Note that task sheets usually also don't start with “Dear students” or similar.

Comment: With all respect @celtschk I don't understand the comparison. If I understand (what you mean about task sheets) the sheets of exercises are edited by professionals in an academic context (universities, high schools or other institutions). These sheets don't ask to the students for help, if I understand well are material means (not a post in a Q&A site) in the context if I say well as curriculum of academy. Maybe one could to interpret a "Hi" as a expression of communication, I don't know what is the specific motivation or interpretation for a "Hi" as prelude when one is asking for help here.

Comment: @user759001: The question here are part of a repository of relevant questions and corresponding answers. The main use of the site is intended to be finding existing questions. If you don't find an existing question that solves your problem, it probably means that this question is missing from the repository (it may, of course, also mean that it is not appropriate for this site), therefore you write it down yourself so that others (or you yourself!) can provide answers. In particular, this is *not* a forum. You are not asking for help, you are providing a question to the repository.

Comment: I totally agree with these sentiments, but do think learning and fun should go hand in hand. As an aside, I noticed that OP's post was edited by another user, and I went to check the original post, and was oddly disappointed this post itself didn't start with "Hi!" :).

Comment: @doubled Sorry to disappoint! Can't be too certain where formalities are allowed ;)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you start your question with "Hi! Hi!"? Are both "Hi!"s removed or only the first one? I'm not high (pun intended), just curious.

Comment: "Hi" and other throat-clearing should be eliminated.  See:  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/31696/210401

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It's considered [noise](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/295232) because it distracts from the main content of the question. Stack Exchange is a little different from other sites on the Internet; content is key.

Since opening a post with 'Hi' was so common, already in the early days of Stack Exchange a [script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/295232) was written to remove such greetings automatically.

Comment: Which makes me curious why "please help me" isn't also automatically removed!

Comment: StackExchange: Our users are too unfriendly and cold!  In the future, please accept poorly written homework problems on good faith and leave lots of welcoming comments.

Also StackExchange: The 1000 year old English convention for friendly greeting takes up much too much space. Let's silently eliminate it.

Comment: @hunter Nice meme